# log a output of a command?

Tags: batch-file, logging

I wanted to make a logging function for my batch app and what I want this function to do is save the output of a command. As an example lets take a simple command such as

```
copy "data" "C:\Program Files"
```

where in the folder data is "text.txt" & "text2.txt". The output of the command would be

```
C:\users\%username%\desktop\testFolder\data\text.txt -> C:\Program Files\data\
C:\users\%username%\desktop\testFolder\data\text2.txt -> C:\Program Files\data\
2 file(s) copied
```

I want this to be saved into lets say "output.log" which would be in the same folder as the folder "data" which was copied. is there a way to do this?

Comment: See more [article](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true). Example to redirect output and error output both in log file:: `abc.exe>>output.log 2>&1`

Comment: There is a destination `data` directory and a source `data` directory, to which one do you want `output.log` saved? If it's the source directory you may need to be careful that it doesn't also become a copied file too!

Answer (score 0):

`>` character is what you need.

---

```
command > log.txt
```

Creates and overwrite content of `log.txt` with `command` result.

```
command >> log.txt
```

Creates or append content of `log.txt` with `command`result.

```
command >> log.txt 2>&1
```

Creates or append content of `log.txt` with `command` result and error.